# ElasticSearch- How to query one result from 30 million documents quickly

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Now the situation is we want to search 3 million times from ElasticSearch in a short time.
For test we set up one Es cluster with 4 cores cpu and 16G memory.And this will take about 8 hours.
The query we use is:

```
 GET XXX/TYPE/_search
{
"query": {
"match": {
     "poiName": {
       "query": "XXXXX"
       , "operator": "or"
     }
    }
   }
}
```

And we  use java http request to query ElasticSearch with hadoop.

```
        URL url = new URL(searchUrl);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter wr= new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
        String query = getQueryJson(field,value);
        wr.write(query);
        wr.flush();
        int HttpResult =con.getResponseCode();
        if(HttpResult ==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            br.close();

        }
```

In fact,we only need one result response.How can i improve this?

===================update===============================

For my task :

The document is something like {"doc_name":"An Foo Eoo","name_id:123456","other filed":"value"}.

We query "Ann Foo Eoo" from the ES to get the name_id, but we donot need the all hits.

We will query 3 million different doc_name  from the ElasticSearch.

Actually ,we only need the most match result, and do not care how much the score is.
Attach my terms query .The minimum_match is depend on the size of poiName.

(ps. minimum_match = Math.ceil(terms size of poiName) /2 )

```
GET XXX/TYPE/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "poiName": [
        "An",
        "Foo",
        "Eoo"
      ],
      "minimum_match":2
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: is it something like "search for 3 different million terms" in my index?

Comment: Yes , we will search for 3 different million terms

Comment: could you explain your task more widely? if you query against string of 3 million terms, it returns documents, sorted by score. Do you need this? or you want just to filter documents by specific terms. Maybe it's possible to denormalize your structure and create something like "term group", "term supergroup" to reduce number of applicable terms?

Comment: Ok i will explain my task and update my term query